# MVC 5 difficult to Routing RedirectToAction. Not Open View

Tags: model, controller, routes

i have this problem:

I have HomeController that call a RedirectToAction("Index", "UsersList");

And it work, but when call an action link (on index):

```
@model IEnumerable<WhatsAppSender.Models.UsersList>
...
...
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "UsersList")
</p>


// GET: UsersList/Create
 public ActionResult Create()
{
  ___ THIS OK ___ i arrive in this point

   return View();
}
```

NOT OPEN A Create View, but

if i call directly a http://  localhost:2250  / UsersList/Create

It's work ..............

Than you :) :) i don't know

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use href in the paragraph

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create","UsersList")">Create New</a>
```